# No se establece conexión local con base de datos en servidor CPANEL

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

estoy realizando una conexión local a una base de datos MySQL montada en un servidor de Neubox (proveedor de servicios de dominios y hostings), pero resulta que no se hace la conexión y me manda el siguiente error

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'mermelan_root'@'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\conPHPMySQL.php on line 7
Connection failed: Access denied for user 'mermelan_root'@'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' (using password: YES).
```

Les comparto mi conexión y espero que me puedan apoyar a detectar la falla.

Conexión

```
<?php
    $servername = "xx.xx.xx.xx";
    $database = "llamadas";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "javierfr117";
    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

> Captura de pantalla CPANEL (se muestra la IP que coloque en la
> conexión).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Se los agradecería mucho.

Saludos y fonito fin de semana.

Comment: Estas intentando acceder de manera remota a tu servidor desde localhost. Debes dar permiso desde tu cpanel para que tu ip local pueda acceder. Busca en tu cpanel 'MySql Remoto' e ingresa tu ip. Si no tienes habilitada la opción contacta con tu proveedor de hosting.

Comment: Otra cosa oculta los datos sensibles que aparecen en tus errores (esta expuesto el nombre de usuario, contraseña y ip del host)

Comment: No me deja, ya coloque mi ip y nada.

Comment: Como ya ha comentado @RicardoCamposVillarroel necesitas autorizar la dirección IP de tu equipo local en cPanel. OJO, se trata de la IP pública que se le asigna a tu router para navegar por internet. Si esa IP suele cambiar pero usa un mismo rango, puedes autorizar rangos de IP. De todos modos lo más seguro sería crear un túnel y usar llaves privadas / públicas, pero algunos hosting no permiten esa opción. Otra cosa que te falta es pasar el puerto, sería un 5º parámetro que pasarías a `mysqli_connect` con el puerto donde está corriendo MySQL en el servidor (suele ser `3306`)  pero verifícalo.

Comment: Ya quedo. Me comunique con el proveedor y listo. Muchas gracias por su ayuda @RicardoCamposVillarroel y A. Cedano

Comment: @Javierfr te recomiendo cambiar las credenciales en ese servidor de BD porque la IP real y las credenciales reales están en el historial de la pregunta :/ :/

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias. Saludos y excelente inicio de semana y a darle con todo mis programadores(esperancitos)!!!!